# Control the order in which category filters are displayed in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories, elementor

I have a Wordpress site for a new subdivision development. I am using this [PEMBE THEME](https://themeforest.net/item/pembe-interior-architecture-wordpress-theme/36670176/) which uses Elementor as page builder.

Furthermore, I am creating posts for a type, 'Portfolio.' The posts have a few categories for the type of home: Bungalow, Craftsman, etc... The number of bathrooms... The basic stuff.

The theme has the typical 'portfolio grid' page to display all the individual portfolio posts: https://walkerheights.com/portfolio-grid/

You can see the categories listed above the images of the various posts. When you click one of the categories, the expected behavior of filtering the posts happens.

What I am struggling with is how to control the order in which the categories are displayed. I have tried [Category Order and Taxonomy Terms Order](https://https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/) plugin.

The plugin does "change" the order in which the categories are displayed, but not in the order that I put them in. Here are the categories without the plugin activated:

Without the plugin active:

[image: Without the plugin active]

With the plugin active:

[image: With the plugin active]

The list of categories as WP shows them:

[image: The list of categories as WP shows them]

The list of categories as the plugin shows them:

[image: The list of categories as the plugin shows them]

Please note that the way that WP is showing them in the dashboard is identical to how the plugin has allowed me to rearrange them in the order that I want, but they are not actually displayed in that way on the actual page. It seems like there is *some* pattern to the way it's displaying the categories...

The first option is 'All Items' That makes sense. The next option is 'Bungalow' which *is* one of the first option for what should be the first category displayed, 'Archetype' and the last category shown is 'Walkout' which is also correct. It feels almost like WP is making a table or array of all the categories and going down the list and picking one item from each column in the table. Does that make any sense?

So, how can I control the order in which the category links are displayed?

I have installed a plugin to attempt to control the order of the categories. I have consulted the all mighty ChatGPT and given it my HTML and my CSS. It was unable to help me. It was having a rough day and didn't feel like reading my HTML.

Elementor has an option to turn the list of categories on and off, but not arrange their order.

I have read over this stack overflow thread:

Maybe this is what I need to do: [Custom Order for Categories in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761897/custom-order-for-categories-in-wordpress)

My answer might be somewhere in the answer of that post, but php is WAY outside my wheelhouse. If anyone can give me an example of how to do this... where to get the numbers of the categories... where do I add the php code into my site? I will attempt to follow it through.

Nota bene:

I edited the post to correct the second image showing the change that the plugin does to the order of the categories. I originally uploaded the same image, showing the page with the plugin deactivated, for both links.

Comment: Have you tried checked if there is a specific value for the menu order added to each entry (Quick Edit > Order)? ASAIK that ordering plugin should take precedence but it's worth checking. Failing that, you will need to check the code to see if there is a custom sort being implemented either in your theme code or one of your plugins. In either case, you may need to contact the theme/plugin developer to ask about how to change it